# The Windows Azure SDK for .NET must be installed

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure, visual-studio-lightswitch, web-platform-installer, azure-sdk-.net

I'm trying to publish my app to Azure which I have done several times before. For some reason I'm now getting the following error:

> The Windows Azure SDK for .Net must be installed to enable publishing
>   to Windows Azure. LightSwitch will load a web page to begin
>   installation.

It loads a web page, downloads V11AzurePack_1_8_1.exe which in turn runs the Web Platform Installer 4.6 which in turn installs Windows Azure SDK Tools 1.8.1 for Visual Studio 2012. All of this succeeds. But going back and attempting to Publish results in the same error.

I noticed that there is a Windows Azure SDK for .Net (VS 2012) - 2.2 in the WPI. So I installed that manually, tried to publish, same result.

The SDK is clearly installed:

[image: Web Platform Installer Azure Installed]

So why can't I publish to Azure? The only thing that looks like it might be a problem is that I have LightSwtich Azure Publishing 1.1 add-on for Visual Studio 2012 installed and I know there is a newer version of that available. But I can't find a direct download nor can I find a way to uninstall that package or force WPI to suggest an update.

---

Uninstalling everything Azure related (except the LightSwitch add-on as that seems to be unremovable and un-upgradeable), rebooting, and installing only the latest SDK produces the same problem.

[image: Only 2.2 installed]

---

After following a moderator's advice to repair Visual Studio on the forum, I was no longer able to open my project at all. I waited for a response but got none. So I decided to reinstall Visual Studio all together.

I followed [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2011/11/08/clean-up-after-visual-studio.aspx) and [this](http://wiki.visualwebgui.com/pages/index.php/Clearing_Cache) in order to remove as much of Visual Studio as possible and then reinstalled. I then installed Update 4 and was again able to open my project.

However, upon trying to publish, the same error was encountered.

---

I decided to upgrade my project to VS2013. That all seemed to go well. Wnet o Publish to Azure and it claimed that it succeeded. However going to Azure and launching the app's site brought up the previous version.

I deleted my Azure cloud service and started a new project in VS2013. I copied over one of my screens to have something to run. I then tried to publish to Azure. It again told me it succeeded but the site did not exist in the Azure Management portal. However, it did realize that I had created a new self-signed certificate so there was some type of communication there. Just not an actual Publish.

Then I did something really stupid. I uninstalled the Azure SDK and tried to reinstall it thinking that was the problem. Now I'm back to where I was before. An endless loop asking me to install the Azure SDK.

---

I wiped out all of my Azure services. Did a system restore to a month ago. Reinstalled the Azure SDK. This then allowed me to "Publish".

Not really.

Visual Studio claimed that the Publish Succeeded. The services were created and the certificate uploaded but nothing was deployed. I then did a manual deploy and the Production instance began to be deployed.

Everything seems to be running but I cannot access my app's site. I receive a 403 Forbidden error message. With or without HTTPS required. But this seems to be a different issue so I'm going to open another question on it.

Why these extreme measures were required is beyond me. This continual breaking of LightSwitch to Azure publishing is getting to be absurd though.